# im not able to makemigrations to my already built model after extending user model to it in django

Tags: django, makemigrations

im just stuck with error while making migrations to my django project.
in my project which is already 50% dveloped i use owner model to represent owner of shop and then i used user model for login and for registration purpose.
so i tried to use user model in my owner model so i could utilise both model effectively with additional fields.
 **i tried to extend user model in owner model** using onetoone field.
after doing that i was not able to do migrations so i deleted all migrations files but after that it was start giving this error while doing migrations:-

```
py manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 87, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\Mayur\PycharmProjects\StartUp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration listings.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('owners', '0001_initial')
```

here is my Owner Model :-

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Owner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=False)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

im hoping that will get help on this because i'm totally stuck here and also not getting how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Did you delete the database rows in the django_migrations table?

Comment: no i didnt deleted any rows or data from database. what i did is only 0001 and 002 migrations file from migration folder of my django project.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the term "migration folder of my django project" (in a comment above), and that is wrong -- each app in your project has its own migration folder. Specifically, there is still a migration in your "listings" app, and it lists as a dependency one of the migrations you deleted.

Comment: yes i  deleted files from owner app migration folder. in my listing app i have 0001 file under its migration folder.

Answer (score 0):

after reviewing and debugging that stack trace i finally get rid of that problem.
i delete the migration file 0001 from my listing app which was having relationship with Owner Model and then when i run makemigrations command it didn't given me any error or exception like i mentioned above.